# Android Layout positioning incorrectly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to create a layout for list child. Here is what it should look like:
[image]

But when the text for Name is large it is displaced like:
[image]

I'm using the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/text_blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="51" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tranID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="11"
        android:background="@color/app_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/tranid"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@color/app_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/app_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/app_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="11"
        android:background="@color/app_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I need it emergency. Would you like to help me?

Comment: This looks like a screenshot from eclipse's ui builder, which is notoriously bad at showing layout changes properly on the fly.  What does it actually look like when you execute it?

Comment: You can try: android:singleline="true"

Comment: When using weights, you should be specifying the width as "0dp". Check to see what it actually looks like in the app, but you may need to scale the text size so it always fits within your TextView.

Comment: @AleksG It's same while running

Comment: @confused_at_times Actually it depends on how you want to calculate weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `layout_height` like below for the `TextView`.[image]

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: He should be using "match_parent" for all the child views, actually.

Answer (score 0):

you can try: android:singleline="true"

Comment: suggestions must be a comment.